# Why Postgresql latest stable release is not in Debian stable repository yet?

Tags: debian, postgresql

I can see that today v15 is the stable one version for Postgresql on Debian 12 (here: https://packages.debian.org/bookworm/postgresql).

But v16 is the latest one Postgresql stable released on 2023 September 14.

Why is not in the Debian 12 repository yet?

Comment: [I would use these instructions to install whatever version you want to install](https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/debian/)

Comment: Why would it be? Debian is all about stability. Seeing how upgrades between Postgres major versions are an involved manual process, it would be highly questionable to do this in Debian 12, released on June 10th, 2013.

Comment: Ah, or does your confusion perhaps stem from the fact that Debian is not a rolling-release distro?

Comment: [Debian 12](https://www.debian.org/releases/bookworm/) was released on June 10th 2023 not 2013.  [Debian 12.5](https://www.debian.org/releases/bookworm/) was released in February 2024.